# Error property of non-object in JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to integrate the API of a game via cURL, I tried with the code that you see below, however, gives me error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\over\index.php on line 173

JSON is not "data" and I think that's what bothers me:

```
{"SoloKills": "494", "DamageDone": "758,071", "Eliminations": "1,911",}



$mode = "quick-play";
$allheroes = curl_init();
curl_setopt($allheroes, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($allheroes, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($allheroes, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($allheroes, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.lootbox.eu/{$platform}/{$country}/{$battletag}/quick-play/allHeroes/");
$result3 = curl_exec($allheroes);
curl_close($allheroes);
$stats3 = json_decode($result3, true);
foreach ($stats3 as $allhero)
{ 
$uccisioni = $allhero['Eliminations'];
echo $uccisioni;
}
```

Comment: What's code on line 173 of index.php?

Comment: line 173: `$uccisioni = $allhero['ObjectiveKills'];`

{$platform}/{$country}/{$battletag} = pc/eu/buff-21986

Answer (score 0):

You don't have key "ObjectiveKills" at this JSON

`{"SoloKills": "494", "DamageDone": "758,071", "Eliminations": "1,911"}`

But i think you can get "SoloKills", "DamageDone", "Eliminations" like:

`foreach ($stats3 as $allhero) { 
    $uccisioni = $allhero['SoloKills'];
    echo $uccisioni;
}`

Update:

You don't need foreach here, I got

`array(41) { ["SoloKills"]=> string(2) "55" ["ObjectiveKills"]=> string(3) "138" ...]}`

You can get $stats3['Eliminations']

Comment: It returns the same error.. the URL of the JSON is: https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/buff-21986/quick-play/allHeroes/ and I would extract Eliminations

Comment: You don't need foreach here, I got `array(41) { ["SoloKills"]=> string(2) "55" ["ObjectiveKills"]=> string(3) "138"...`. You can get $stats3['Eliminations']

Answer (score 0):

You have to becarefull in encoding. It's affect to whole your codes

```
"DamageDone": "758,071"
```

not

```
DamageDone": "758,071"
```

you've forgot **Quote Marks**!

Comment: Sorry I copied a bad part of json, but I'm trying to decompose the data from a url "https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/buff-21986/quick-play/allHeroes/"